# Error: xhr post error at Heroku on Flask-SocketIO based application

Tags: python, flask, heroku, socket.io, flask-socketio

I deployed the flask application on Heroku.

**application.py** contents:

```
    import os
    from flask import Flask, render_template
    from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, join_room, leave_room
    app = Flask(__name__)
    socketio = SocketIO(app)

    #my stuff

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        socketio.run(app)
```

**requirements.txt** contents:

```
Flask
Flask-SocketIO
gunicorn
eventlet
```

**Procfile** contents:

```
web: gunicorn -k eventlet application:app
```

**client JS code** contents:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
```

The application runs, I can see its front-end. But the browser sends the alert: **Error: xhr post error**

In console I see:

```
socket.io.min.js:2 WebSocket connection to 'wss://.....herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=0838a049bc124fc18c320fd489ff1935' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established. n.doClose @ socket.io.min.js:2 

socket.io.min.js:1 POST https://......herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1583010125065-6&sid=442aedb87e2741968afca2574386ce30 400 (BAD REQUEST)
```

Could you please give an advice where I am going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: doesn't it shows for what url it gives error? In standard Flask you have to set `@app.route(..., methods=['GET', 'POST'])` to use `POST` requests because normally it blocks `POST` and sends `BAD REQUEST`

Comment: always add code, data and error messages in question, not comment - it will be more readable and more people will see. And always add it when you write question because it is always very important information.

Comment: OK, moved info in question

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I have the exact same problem